# How to show values from two different queries?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have one database that contains all of user information including name.  Then there is a second database that contains notes from the users and it contains the #id but not the name.  The query i am doing to retrieve user notes doesn't have name so all its doing is showing the notes, then right under it i am doing another query to retrieve the name from the first database using the common #id.  But it won't show.

Is there a way I can do this query in one? Please help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT u.name,
          n.*
     FROM DB2.NOTES n
LEFT JOIN DB1.USERS u ON n.id = u.id
 ORDER BY u.name
```

Assuming the connection credentials has access to both databases, you prefix the database name in front of the table name and separate with a period.

The LEFT JOIN will show both users, and notes without users associated.  Here's a [good primer on JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 1):

You might need to show your code, but you can write queries against two databases (or schemas) on the same host, just qualify the table names with the database name, e.g.

```
SELECT db1.user.id, db1.user.name, db2.userinfo.notes
FROM db1.user
INNER JOIN  db2.userinfo ON(db1.user.id=db2.userinfo.id)
```

The credentials you are connecting with must have access to both databases for this to work of course.